# How to loop through multiple value from a text file in Fortran and write those values in a new text file

Tags: fortran, text-files, readfile, do-loops

```
PROGRAM Lab

IMPLICIT NONE
! Declare variables used in the program
INTEGER :: openStatus, ioStatus
INTEGER :: counter = 0            
REAL :: temperature, volume          
REAL :: sum_temps = 0.0, sum_vols = 0.0        
REAL :: max_temp, min_vol
REAL :: mean_temp, mean_vol                 

! Open the file on i/o unit 12
OPEN (UNIT = 12, FILE = 'Lab.dat', STATUS = "OLD", ACTION = "READ", IOSTAT = openStatus)

! Check for errors on open      
IF (openStatus > 0) THEN
  WRITE (*,*) "*** Cannot open Lab.dat ***"
  STOP
END IF

DO
   ! Read the data from the file  
   READ(12, 10, IOSTAT = ioStatus) temperature, volume
   10 FORMAT(T1, F5.2, T9, F5.2)

   IF (counter == 0) THEN
      max_temp = temperature
      min_vol = volume
   END IF

   ! Check if the end of the file is reached
   IF (ioStatus < 0) THEN
      WRITE (*,*)  "*** End of file ***"
      EXIT
   END IF

   ! Find the sums
   sum_temps = sum_temps + temperature
   sum_vols = sum_vols + volume

   ! Find the maximum temperature
   IF (temperature > max_temp) THEN
      max_temp = temperature
   END IF
   ! Find the minimum volume
   IF (volume < min_vol) THEN
      min_vol = volume
   END IF

   ! Count the number of data
   counter = counter + 1

END DO

! Calculate the means
mean_temp = sum_temps / counter
mean_vol = sum_vols / counter

! Create a new file whose i/o unit number is 20
OPEN (UNIT=20, FILE='Report.dat', STATUS="NEW", ACTION="READWRITE", IOSTAT=OpenStatus)

! If the file was not created successfully,
! tell the user and then terminate the program.
IF (OpenStatus > 0) THEN
  WRITE (*, *) "*** Cannot open the file ***"
  STOP
END IF

WRITE (20, 110) "Temperature", "Volume"
WRITE (20, 110) "=======", "======"
110 FORMAT (T2, A, T17, A)

WRITE(20, 100, IOSTAT = ioStatus) temperature, volume
100 FORMAT(T1, F5.2, T9, F5.2)

WRITE (20, 150) "The highest temperature is:", max_temp
150 FORMAT (T2, A, T35, F5.2)
WRITE (20, 160) "The smallest volume is:", min_vol
160 FORMAT (T2, A, T35, F5.2)
WRITE (20, 170) "The mean of the temperatures is:", mean_temp
170 FORMAT (T2, A, T35, F5.2)
WRITE (20, 180) "The mean of the volumes is:", mean_vol
180 FORMAT (T2, A, T35, F5.2)

! Close the files
CLOSE (12)

! Finish up
STOP
END PROGRAM Lab
```

This is working fine as it is. But, it only shows the last value of temperature and volume in the new text file named 'Report' instead of all the values. How do I loop it such that it shows all the values for both temperature and volume. I am referring to the following part of the code, which is towards the end.

```
WRITE(20, 100, IOSTAT = ioStatus) temperature, volume
100 FORMAT(T1, F5.2, T9, F5.2)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have additional `WRITE`s within the loop? I mean, if you want to have in your output file also some values from your input, you must have some write statements within the loop.

Comment: @FDavidov Could you please provide me some more help. I am not sure what you mean. And, from what I understand you are saying is outputting on the window that opens when I run the program. No, I don't want it there. I want the output to be on a new file that gets created. Putting write statements in the DO loop that I have now will print the content on that window that pops up.

Comment: You want to have within your output file also detailed data retrieved from your input file, right? If so, you need to do one of two options (both within the loop!): (1) Store the information in some array and the use the stored information when writing into the output file (you will need another loop); (2) Open your OUTPUT file before the loop and write into it whatever you want from the read record.

Comment: I am not allowed to use arrays. It hasn't been introduced, so I don't know how to use it. Could you please modify the code, and point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a site for answering questions posted by students. I gave you clear guidelines towards the solution. Spend some additional time thinking about what you are doing wrong and the solution will certainly pop. Think **PROCEDURALLY** (step by step what you want the code to do, and what you need for the code to do it). Though you might dislike my answer, I would strongly recommend you to TRUST ME, this is the very best answer I could give you. Good luck!!!

Comment: I can't use arrays. So, could you give me a better answer?

Comment: I presented you two options, including one WITHOUT arrays.

Comment: I got it. Don't worry about it. Actually I think I used your second option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pleased to read that. By the way, if my comment served you in any way, you may consider up-voting it. Thanks.